# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads error

Tags: android

I am getting below error in DashboardFragment. I am using SharedPreference in Login. Not using ContentProvider/URI don't know if any subprocess is using.

Got below log while screen of my app was reloading repeatedly. Very upsate since last 1 month because of this issue.

```
Model : SM-G925F
Brand : samsung
Product : zeroltexx
Device : zerolte
Codename : REL
Release : 7.0
```

Log Details

```
12-11 22:55:30.922 16436-16460/? E/radish: radish_send_nd_packet sent 72 bytes
12-11 22:55:35.751 27114-31855/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/5251
                                                      at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.query(DownloadProvider.java:1026)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1028)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:569)
12-11 22:55:35.931 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
12-11 22:55:35.933 16436-16460/? E/radish: radish_send_nd_packet sent 72 bytes
12-11 22:55:36.200 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
12-11 22:55:39.962 14099-20800/? E/AD-PLUGIN-PullRedirectUrlServer: parseHttpResponse: {"status":20,"code":300400,"interval":8}
12-11 22:55:39.986 14099-20800/? E/AD-PLUGIN-RedirectUrlController: GetRedirectUrl response is null
12-11 22:55:41.631 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
12-11 22:55:46.180 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
12-11 22:55:49.461 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
12-11 22:55:51.631 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
12-11 22:55:51.632 16436-16460/? E/radish: radish_send_nd_packet sent 72 bytes
12-11 22:55:55.860 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
12-11 22:55:56.422 16436-16460/? E/radish: radish_send_nd_packet sent 72 bytes
12-11 22:55:56.815 27114-27130/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/5251
                                                      at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.query(DownloadProvider.java:1026)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1028)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
                                                      at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:569)
12-11 22:56:01.431 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
12-11 22:56:01.455 16436-16460/? E/radish: radish_send_nd_packet sent 72 bytes
12-11 22:56:05.840 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
12-11 22:56:11.580 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
12-11 22:56:13.660 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
12-11 22:56:16.650 712-712/? E/cnss-daemon: Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29175716/1531971 What research have you done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content:// CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175716/illegalargumentexception-unknown-url-content-content)